# Getting Windows 8 Contact Info Without Picker

Tags: windows-8

I have reviewed the few number of windows 8 contact questions on here, as well as the MSDN Contact picker sample and couldn't find an answer to my question.

It seems like, from most answers, the only way to get contact information from the people contract is to have the user manually choose the people they want the information for.

That doesn't seem completely right, since in the mail and messenger apps, they have found a way to get contact information for people that email or IM you without me choosing those people.

How do you go about accomplishing this programmatically? I would like to be able to pull either all contact data at once or get contact data by looking up specific emails linked to those users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that in the Mail, People and Messaging apps, they are using details pulled straight from the users Windows Live account. I think you should be able to do this in your app, look here for documentation on the Live SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/

Comment: This is the conclusion that I came to the other day about this- because they are all actually contained within the same app in windows 8, they probably are able to share information between the people app and messenger app, which explains the behavior that I observed. Thank you for the link to the sdk. I'll definitely check that out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do this right now without a Picker. This would vioalate some security restrictions. But if you find a way, please post it here.